# is any function to modify the json parse dictionary array

Tags: swift

i have dictionary array  in witch i have to modify the array object isRead

```
let dict = arr[indexPath]
    var Added = dict["IsRead"] as! NSNumber

    if Added == 0
    {
        Added =  1
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your json file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `NSNumber`? The name `isRead` implies that the type is `Bool`.

Due to value semantics you have to modify `arr`

```
let dict = arr[indexPath.row]
if let isRead = dict["IsRead"] as? Bool, isRead == false {
   arr[indexPath.row]["IsRead"] = true
}
```

Comment: it is giving error like Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only

Comment: `arr` must be a `var`iable.